# Magento Order History Comments: Modify Date

Tags: magento

I am creating a script to add orders programmatically in Magento. I need help to change the date of the entries in the Comments History (quote, invoice, shipping, etc.). I can manipulate the date of the order itself (setCreatedAt) and some of the comments related to the creation of the order are correct (e.g. "Sep 29, 2008 8:59:25 AM|Pending Customer Notification Not Applicable"), but I cannot change the date of the comment when I use addStatusHistoryComment...

Here's a snippet of my code:

```
try {
if(!$order->canInvoice()) {
  Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice.'));
}
$invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
  Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Cannot create an invoice without   products.'));
}

$invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase(Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Invoice::CAPTURE_OFFLINE);
$invoice->setCreatedAt('2008-09-23 13:05:20');
$invoice->register();
$invoice->getOrder()->setCustomerNoteNotify(true);
$invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
  ->addObject($invoice)
-  >addObject($invoice->getOrder());

$transactionSave->save();
//END Handle Invoice

//START Handle Shipment
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment();
$shipment->setCreatedAt('2008-09-23 14:20:10');
$shipment->register();
$order->setIsInProcess(true);
$order->addStatusHistoryComment('Shipping message goes here...', true);
$shipment->setEmailSent(true);
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
  ->addObject($shipment)
  ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
  ->save();
$track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
  ->setShipment($shipment)
  ->setData('title', 'Some tracking no.')
  ->setData('number', '111222333444')
  ->setData('carrier_code', 'fedex') //custom, fedex, ups, usps, dhl
  ->setData('order_id', $shipment->getData('order_id'))
  ->save();
//END Handle Shipment
}
catch (Mage_Core_Exception $ex) {
  echo "Problem creating order invoice and/or shipment: ".$ex."\n";
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to do this:

```
$comments = $order->getStatusHistoryCollection(true);
```

`$comments` now contains a collection of all the status history comments, and you can loop over them with whatever sort of criteria you like.

```
foreach ($comments as $c) {
    if ( /* some stuff */ ) {
        $c->setData('created_at',$new_date)->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice spot better than my solution, love the methods description "Enter description here..." :)

Comment: Yeah, it's fun looking on docs.magentocommerce.com and later realizing that method you were hoping existed but wasn't listed... exists. It's good as a rough guide and not much else because you just can't trust it. How nice of them.

Answer (score 0):

So this is untested, but should work:

You need to create a new method based off `addStatusHistoryComment`:
`/app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php`

```
/*
 * Add a comment to order
 * Different or default status may be specified
 *
 * @param string $comment
 * @param string $status
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Status_History
 */
public function addStatusHistoryComment($comment, $status = false)
{
    if (false === $status) {
        $status = $this->getStatus();
    } elseif (true === $status) {
        $status = $this->getConfig()->getStateDefaultStatus($this->getState());
    } else {
        $this->setStatus($status);
    }
    $history = Mage::getModel('sales/order_status_history')
        ->setStatus($status)
        ->setComment($comment)
        ->setEntityName($this->_historyEntityName);
        ->setCreatedAt('2008-09-23 14:20:10'); //I added this line
    $this->addStatusHistory($history);
    return $history;
}
```

Obviously you either need to rewrite this method, or refactor the code to do the same.

Comment: Thanks, input. I've already tried modifying the existing method (just to see if it would work before I went to the trouble of extending the source), but it no worky...